# I can't see any trace output in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

In Visual Studio 2010 I added Trace to Page_Load as explained here http://www.asp101.com/articles/robert/tracing/default.asp but I can't see any Trace output, why ?

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page {

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        Trace.IsEnabled = true;
        Trace.Write("Hello World");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

do you have something like that in your web.config?

```
<system.web>
      <trace enabled ="true" pageOutput ="true"  />        
</system.web>
```

check [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13fw6we(VS.71).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to check that the following is not set in your machine config:

```
 <deployment retail="true" />
```

$WINDOWS$\Microsoft.NET\Framework\version\CONFIG

This setting disables tracing for all sites on a machine regardless of the web.config and page settings